# connected-react-router and office-ui-fabric-react <Nav>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric, connected-react-router

Related post on [Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/915#issuecomment-437773980)

Currently I have a hard time using the two libraries in my react-redux app correctly.

My codes look like:

index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
...
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```
...
export default () => (
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
);
```

Layout.js

```
...
export default function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <div class="ms-Fabric">
      <div class="ms-Grid-row">
        <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-lg2">
          <Navigation />
        </div>
        <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-lg10">{props.children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export default withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <div className="ms-NavExample-LeftPane">
    <Nav
      onLinkClick={(event, element) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.push(element.url);
      }}
      groups={[
        {
          links: [
            {
              name: 'Home',
              url: '/',
              key: 'home'
            },
            {
              name: 'Test',
              url: '/Test',
              key: 'test'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]}
    />
  </div>
));
```

However, when I run the app it shows `You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>`. The navigation is certainly in the `ConnectedRouter` and [it seems](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) this router works well with `react-router` v4 so I'm not sure how to deal with this problem.

Could anyone please give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of your project:
Provider > ConnectedRouter > App > Layout (have NavLink) > Switch > Routes

You have to build architecture in this way:
Provider > ConnectedRouter > routes file > Switch > Routes > Layout in component

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import routes from 'routes/index';
import store from 'store/configureStore';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      {routes}
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

// routes.js
const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
  </Switch>
);

export default routes;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where in your example can I put the layout?

Comment: You can use pattern HOC and use it in routes file. Example:  <Route path="/test" component={Layout(Test)} />. Or put Layout in component.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the reply. I tried HOC method but it gives `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` and am not sure how to use the other one. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: You need pass all props. Read this article https://medium.com/@soorajchandran/introduction-to-higher-order-components-hoc-in-react-383c9343a3aa